# Unload/close a popup form after adding one row

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a popup form in Access `frmAddComposerWork` which is open with Data Entry set to **Yes**, where there are 2 text boxes: One for the composer name and the other for the Work title.

After filling the last text box, when I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (to update the table behind with the new record) I want to close the form as well. I have tried several events on which I added the following VBA instruction:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.frmAddComposerWork
```

However, the form stays open and is prone to receive a new record (which I do not want at all).

How can I make the form close itself after adding a single row?

Comment: Double-click the last textbox; the VBE will generate an event handler for the default event of a `TextBox` control (e.g. `TextBox42_Change`) - you'll want to use the top-right dropdown in the VBE code pane to select another event, one that's fired at every keypress (e.g. `KeyDown`); test the parameter to validate whether the key was {ENTER}, in which case you can proceed to close the form; discard the auto-generated `Change` handler if you don't need it.

Comment: `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` or `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAddComposerWork"` You code should raise an error unless you have a control named `frmAddComposerWork` on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the form close itself from its *After Insert* event.

```vba
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:=Me.Name, Save:=acSaveNo
End Sub
```

That simple approach achieves your goal as I understand it:

1. You have the form open in *Data Entry* mode --- meaning it displays only a new blank record.
2. The user can add values for the new row, but not navigate to any existing rows.
3. After the user completes the addition of that single new row, the form closes.

Answer (score 0):

**To close form after hitting Enter on last textbox**

```
Private Sub Text2_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
     If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
     End If
End Sub
```

---

**To close when you hit Enter anywhere on form**

KeyPreview property is set to True in the form's Load event procedure. This causes the form to receive keyboard events before they are received by any control

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

On pressing enter anywhere on the form it will close

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
       DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
End Sub
```